# Adding a created variable holding a score and inserting this score into an SQL database C#

Tags: c#, sql, variables

I have created a simple quiz, and a variable called score, which depending on what the user enters, increases if their answer is correct. At the end of the quiz the score is calculated and displayed to the user, I would like to know how to insert the variable score into a table, which has an attribute called score.

Can anyone help?

I have a database called db1, the table I want to insert into is user/test, the row I want to insert into is score and the variable I want to insert into is called score.

Something like this .... (i'm not sure what to put in the brackets) `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("); 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(); 
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text; 
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT user/test (Score) VALUES (@score)"; 
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1; 
sqlConnection1.Open(); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
sqlConnection1.Close();`

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question is pretty broad and doesn't pose a specific problem. Maybe this tutorial will help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171884.aspx

Comment: so after the user has been informed of their score. Something like this ....

(i'm not sure what to put in the brackets)


System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = 
    new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(");

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT user/test (Score) VALUES (@score)";
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();

Comment: Please edit the question to include that ^. Make sure to format it so it can be read.

Comment: ok sure, thanks for having a look at it

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples of how to perform an INSERT into an SQL Database across both StackOverflow and the internet. Please make sure you search for the solution first.

Here's a link to the MSDN on how to INSERT into an SQL Database:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812.aspx

```
var ScorePersonGot = 100;
string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=databasename;User ID =root; Password=pass";
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString); 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO user/test (Score) VALUES (@Score)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", ScorePersonGot); 
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1; 
sqlConnection1.Open(); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Comment: I understand how to use insert, it's more using the variable created and inserting that into the table

Comment: You will use SQLParamaters to create and then set the value of the parameters. http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlparameter

Comment: Thanks for your time. As you can tell I'm new to c#. I was wondering if you could check this, the table I want to insert the variable into is called 'user/test', the attribute I want to insert it into in the table is called 'score' and the variable I have created is called score.

Comment: i'm not sure what to put in the brackets) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("); System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(); cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text; cmd.CommandText = "INSERT user/test (Score) VALUES (@score)"; cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1; 
sqlConnection1.Open(); cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); sqlConnection1.Close();

Comment: You forgot to specify a ConnectionString and add the parameter to it. Also your INSERT command was incorrect. I've updated my original comment.

Comment: thanks a lot, if for example I didn't need a userID or password if I made it into single user,  could it just be the server and database name? and as the score has already been calculated, the scorepersonGot variable could just be set to 0 or I could just not include "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Score", ScorePersonGot); "

Finally, at the top of the form do I need to declare that I'm using sql?

Comment: Yes, you would need to add the reference to System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: thanks again, i think there is an issue with the server but it should always be localhost, as I am just running it in visual studio

Comment: Please mark as answer if this is what you needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a line that sets the parameter after the command text.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", whateverYourScoreParameterIs);
```

The table is suspect for me as well. Special characters (while you can use them) should be avoided. How are you identifying the user that that score belongs to?

Comment: cheers, it's a single user system, but they can take many tests, so based on an ID

Comment: maybe i should be more specific, so basically its a single user system, however the user can take multiple tests, each test had a test ID so I assume i would have to put a where clause in somewhere as well so the score is entered into the correct place.